# Google Cloud Container Builder fails to push images to container registry

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

My cloud builds used to push result images to GCR, but something happened and I am seeing this in my build logs:

```
PUSH
Pushing gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/zookeeper:9c6def09508c52b9f364aa4751d520c79690e54c
The push refers to a repository [gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/zookeeper]
174a611570d4: Preparing
f51f76255b02: Preparing
51db18d04d72: Preparing
f1c896f31e49: Preparing
0f5ff0cf6a1c: Preparing
0f5ff0cf6a1c: Layer already exists
f51f76255b02: Layer already exists
f1c896f31e49: Layer already exists
51db18d04d72: Layer already exists
174a611570d4: Layer already exists
name unknown: Buckets($PROJECT_ID,artifacts.$PROJECT_ID.appspot.com)
```

The above repeats for every layer. I'm not sure what happened. I recently revoked and re-logged-in with `gcloud auth`. But other `gcloud` commands work and `gsutil` works and shows that the above buckets exist. Permissions look good, but maybe I am missing something?

Comment: I deleted the bucket and it works.

Comment: I too had the similar issue, It got resolved by exporting env variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` with a value pointing to the path of your bucket credentials JSON file eg.

`export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/Users/myuser/Downloads/googleCredentials.json`

This command basically sets default account credentials. This Hope it helps you too.

Comment: Thank you if this happens again I’ll try it out.

Comment: I have the same issue, tried everything here without success. Any idea?

Comment: I deleted and recreated the bucket where the images were pushed, and it started working. No idea why.